# Tinymce alternatives for react

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I would like some alternatives to tinymce which works well and is fully customizable in react. I tried using tinymce but it did not have a lot of documentation on using it with react. So, I would like an alternative solution

Comment: Well it has a React binding, what about that didn't work for you: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#tinymcereactintegrationquickstartguide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use react-rte as an alternative for tinymce.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the content_css option to customise tinymce. Another alternative is CK Editor

Comment: Careful here, CKEditor has a restrictive copyleft license, so bear this in mind.